# Can I insert elements to the beginning of an element using .appendChild()?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

If the user selects an option in a dropdown box, there must be added a label and a textbox. Using `appendChild`, these elements get added to the end of the `container`.

```
var newFreeformLabel = document.createElement('label');
newFreeformLabel.innerHTML = 'Omschrijving:';

var newFreeformField = document.createElement('input');
newFreeformField.className = 'textfield';
newFreeformField.name = 'factuur_orderregel[]';

var newFreeformSpacer = document.createElement('div');
newFreeformSpacer.className = 'spacer';

container.appendChild(newFreeformLabel);
container.appendChild(newFreeformField);
container.appendChild(newFreeformSpacer);
```

The issue is that these elements should be inserted at the beginning of `container`, not at the end.

Is there a solution to this in PrototypeJS?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

As well as `appendChild`, DOM nodes have an [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertBefore) method

```
container.insertBefore(newFreeformLabel, container.firstChild);
```

Comment: Note that this also works if the container doesn't have any elements inside it to begin with.

Answer (score 126):

### Modern Solution

To add a child to the *beginning* of a parent, use `prepend`

```
parent.prepend(newChild)
```

To add at the *end* of a parent, use `append`

```
parent.append(newChild)
```

In addition, if you want to add relative to another child, use one of these:

```
child1.after(newChild)  // [child1, newChild, child2]

child1.before(newChild) // [newChild, child1, child2]
```

### Advanced usage

1. You can pass multiple values (or use spread operator `...`).
2. Any string value will be added as a text element.

**Examples:**

```
parent.prepend(newChild, "foo")  // [newChild, "foo", child1, child2]

const list = ["bar", newChild]
parent.append(...list, "fizz")  // [child1, child2, "bar", newChild, "fizz"]
```

[Related DOM method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40444300/974045) - `child.replaceWith`

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dom-manip-convenience)

Comment: this answer is working, the first answer not worked for me

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Element.insert(element, content)`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/insert/index.html).

Comment: the question is tagged prototypejs, so this really should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
container.
    insert({
        // key is position
        // 'before', 'after', 'top' and 'bottom' are allowed
        top: new Element('label').
            update('Omschrijving:')
    }).
    insert({
        top: new Element('input').
            addClassName('textfield').
            writeAttribute('name', 'factuur_orderregel[]')
    }).
    insert({
        top: new Element('div').
            addClassName('spacer')
    });
```

I think Prototype's `Element.insert` is somewhat awkward for `before`/`after`, however. For instance, if you wanted to place the `.spacer` before the `.textfield`, sometime later in your code, you would need to do something like:

```
container.
    down('.textfield').
    insert({
        before: new Element('div').
            addClassName('spacer')
    });
```

This is, especially if you're familiar with the DOM API's `Element.insertBefore`, somewhat unintuitive, as you are **not** inserting the `.spacer` into the `.textfield`, but instead into the `container`, **before** the `.textfield`.

Answer (score 0):

If I had seen Gareth's solution on time, I might go with that, as it was I used:

```
$('toggle_product').innerHTML = insertContent + $('toggle_product').innerHTML;
```

as Prototypes' insert() function was returning error in IE8..

Comment: with that solution you loose all events

Answer (score 0):

You can add .k-multiselect .k-chip {order: 2} style. Example - https://dojo.telerik.com/uSOnIroB/4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34033040)