# How to replace DOM element in place using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looking to replace an element in the DOM. 
For example, there is an `<a>` element that I want to replace with a `<span>` instead.

How would I go and do that?

Comment: `target.replaceWith(element);` is the modern (ES5+) way to do this

Comment: @Gibolt What does DOM spec have with ES? Moreover, it's not yet a part of the DOM standard, while ES5 was released 9 years ago.

Comment: ES5+ means ES5 OR LATER.  Even if ES5 is 9 years old, later versions are NOT that old.

Comment: If you still use StackOverflow it's worth picking the new standard answer below.

Answer (score 229):

by using [replaceChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <a id="myAnchor" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
  </div>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  var myAnchor = document.getElementById("myAnchor");
  var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
  mySpan.innerHTML = "replaced anchor!";
  myAnchor.parentNode.replaceChild(mySpan, myAnchor);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this example wouldn't work. You should put the script block at the end of the body to make it work. Furthermore, just for fun: try adding the line [alert(myAnchor.innerHTML)] after the operation.

Comment: Theres a spelling mistake with StackOverflow in the anchor innerText

Comment: what if it is root html element

Comment: Thank you @Bjorn Tipling.  I've created a follow up question on how to add an id and a function to the replaced element, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670261/how-to-replace-dom-element-with-js-and-include-an-id-and-a-js-function

Answer (score 153):

## [`A.replaceWith(span)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) - No parent needed

**Generic form:**

```
target.replaceWith(element)
```

Way better/cleaner than the previous method.

**For your use case:**

```
A.replaceWith(span)
```

### Advanced usage

1. You can pass multiple values (or use spread operator `...`).
2. Any string value will be added as a text element.

**Examples:**

```
// Initially [child1, target, child3]

target.replaceWith(span, "foo")     // [child1, span, "foo", child3]

const list = ["bar", span]
target.replaceWith(...list, "fizz")  // [child1, "bar", span, "fizz", child3]
```

#### Safely handling `null` target

If your target has a chance to be null, you can consider using the newish `?.` *optional chaining* operator. Nothing will happen if target doesn't exist. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824031/974045).

```
target?.replaceWith?.(element)
```

### Related DOM methods

1. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656649/974045) - `child.before` and `child.after`
2. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43838105/974045) - `parent.prepend` and `parent.append`

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

[Supported Browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dom-manip-convenience) - 97% Nov '22

Comment: Not supported in IE11 or Edge 14 (now: 2016-11-16).

Comment: Try using Google's Closure or another transpiler to convert to ES5. You shouldn't be writing old code based on browser support, if you have a better, more maintainable option

Comment: Thus transpiling. You can optimize, minify, and down-convert all in one. Check it out: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

Comment: I think if the choice is between use code that works on all browsers I'm trying to support, or re-tool your whole build process to use Closure, I would pick use code that works on all browsers that I'm trying to support.

Comment: @jor I kinda agree to support as many browsers as possible, but I refuse to remade my code just because IE or Edge are incomplete or just "want to be different". There are standards, if they don't follow them and a few people support it, that is their problem, that don't have to affect us as web developers.

Comment: @Davdriver: of course, but the current global support is only 69%: http://caniuse.com/#search=replaceWith

Comment: `replaceWith` has nothing to do with ES5. It is defined by the WHATWG DOM spec.

Comment: Global support is now at 72%, 80% in U.S. as of Oct 2017

Comment: My gulp process didn't transpile this function into something more browser friendly.

Comment: It’s super neat, bit of a bummer that as of January 2019 Safari still offers no support of `replaceWith`. Unless you’re using transpilers/polyfills, I would stick with [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) in meantime.

Comment: Safari and all major modern browsers now support this in Apr 2020.

Comment: It is not my concern that [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) is not supported in Internet Explorer I dropped support for it 11 years ago (IE8). Note that I'm still supporting current minus 10 on browsers that auto update can be turned off and this still works fine.

Answer (score 68):

```
var a = A.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createElement("span"), A);
```

a is the replaced A element.

Comment: Answer from @Bjorn Tipling in fact does not work. This is the (correct!) answer for KooiInc, also correct, comment . Now it works! ;-) Tx to both!

Comment: surely you could have come up with a variable name other than A lol

Answer (score 8):

This question is very old, but I found myself studying for a Microsoft Certification, and in the study book it was suggested to use:

```
oldElement.replaceNode(newElement)
```

I looked it up and it seems to only be supported in IE. Doh..

I thought I'd just add it here as a funny side note ;)

Answer (score 4):

Best way to do it. No parents need. Just use `Element.outerHTML = template;`

```
// Get the current element
var currentNode = document.querySelector('#greeting');

// Replace the element
currentNode.outerHTML =
    '<div id="salutations">' +
        '<h1>Hi, universe!</h1>' +
        '<p>The sun is always shining!</p>' +
    '</div>';
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and found this thread. Replace didn't work for me, and going by the parent was difficult for my situation. Inner Html replaced the children, which wasn't what I wanted either. Using outerHTML got the job done. Hope this helps someone else!

```
currEl = <div>hello</div>
newElem = <span>Goodbye</span>
currEl.outerHTML = newElem
# currEl = <span>Goodbye</span>
```

Comment: This is very clever but I don't know if it complies to the standards. Thanks !

Comment: Probably it is globally used and I vote answer is the best !

Answer (score 3):

You can replace an `HTML Element` or `Node` using `Node.replaceWith(newNode)`.

This example should keep all attributes and childs from origin node:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a')

links.forEach(link => {
  const replacement = document.createElement('span')
  
  // copy attributes
  for (let i = 0; i < link.attributes.length; i++) {
     const attr = link.attributes[i]
     replacement.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value)
  }
  
  // copy content
  replacement.innerHTML = link.innerHTML
  
  // or you can use appendChild instead
  // link.childNodes.forEach(node => replacement.appendChild(node))

  link.replaceWith(replacement)
})
```

If you have these elements:

```html
<a href="#link-1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#link-2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#link-3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#link-4">Link 4</a>
```

After running above codes, you will end up with these elements:

```html
<span href="#link-1">Link 1</span>
<span href="#link-2">Link 2</span>
<span href="#link-3">Link 3</span>
<span href="#link-4">Link 4</span>
```

Comment: The answers given assume a static DOM. What if the DOM has been modified, e.g., via an onload script?

Comment: just make sure that the `document.querySelectorAll('a')` is executed after the DOM has been modified or generated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) on the parent of the target element after creating your new element ([`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)):

```
const newElement = document.createElement(/*...*/);
const target = document.getElementById("my-table");
target.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, target);
```

If your starting point for the new element is HTML, you can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and then [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) on the parent (or [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) on the element itself, in modern environments):

```
const target = document.getElementById("my-table");
target.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", theHTMLForTheNewElement);
target.parentNode.removeChild(target); // Or: `target.remove()`
```

Answer (score -1):

Example for replacing LI elements

```
function (element) {
    let li = element.parentElement;
    let ul = li.parentNode;   
    if (li.nextSibling.nodeName === 'LI') {
        let li_replaced = ul.replaceChild(li, li.nextSibling);
        ul.insertBefore(li_replaced, li);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Given the already proposed options the easiest solution without finding a parent:

```
var parent = document.createElement("div");
var child = parent.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
var span = document.createElement("span");

// for IE
if("replaceNode" in child)
  child.replaceNode(span);

// for other browsers
if("replaceWith" in child)
  child.replaceWith(span);

console.log(parent.outerHTML);
```