# How to set DOM element as first child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom, element

I have an element E and I'm appending some elements to it. All of a sudden, I find out that the next element to append should be the first child of E. What's the trick, how to do it? Method unshift doesn't work because E is an object, not array.

Long way would be to iterate through E's children and to move'em key++, but I'm sure that there is a prettier way.

Comment: You guys are fast! I'm sorry, I think I was misunderstood. 

element e 
        |- child-el_1
        |- child-el_2
        |- child-el_3

And then comes child-el_4 ... which needs to be fit as first child. 

prepend would put child-el_4 before [b]e[/b], am I wrong and tired or what?

Answer (score 732, accepted):

```
var eElement; // some E DOM instance
var newFirstElement; //element which should be first in E

eElement.insertBefore(newFirstElement, eElement.firstChild);
```

Comment: You my friend, just got your self a bear!

Useful extra finding. http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/insertBefore

Comment: For info if there is no element in the parent the child will be added anyway.

Comment: In case of firstChild is text node throws exception. but jquery prepend dousn't.

Comment: @Sergey, works for me with text node too, tested on Firefox and Chromium. What browser did you use? Are you sure the problem was not on your side? Would you care to prepare a snippet/jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: list.outerHTML = entry.outerHTML + list.outerHTML;
Hope helps someone.

Comment: @DenizPorsuk setting outerHTML is destructive IIRC. The elements being re-created lose bound events and variable references.

Comment: @SergeySahakyan use eElement.firstElementChild

Comment: Why this only works with elements created in `javascript` and not with already existing (since pageload) DOM elements? At least for me any methods like `prepend()`, `insertBefore()` etc. just appended the element. Now i needed to `createElement()` programmatically and pass the original elem's properties to the freshly created one. This way prepending worked. Guess it's about some internal node order or so. Someone please explain.  `vanilla js`

Answer (score 320):

## 2018 version - `prepend`

```
parent.prepend(newChild)  // [newChild, child1, child2]
```

This is modern JS! It is more readable than previous options. It is currently available in Chrome, FF, and Opera.

The equivalent for adding to the end is `append`, replacing the old `appendChild`

```
parent.append(newChild)  // [child1, child2, newChild]
```

### Advanced usage

1. You can pass multiple values (or use spread operator `...`).
2. Any string value will be added as a text element.

**Examples:**

```
parent.prepend(newChild, "foo")   // [newChild, "foo", child1, child2]

const list = ["bar", newChild]
parent.append(...list, "fizz")    // [child1, child2, "bar", newChild, "fizz"]
```

### Related DOM methods

1. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656649/974045) - `child.before` and `child.after`
2. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40444300/974045) - `child.replaceWith`

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dom-manip-convenience)

Comment: Great solution, thanks! It irks me that they decided adding a child to the end is `.appendChild()` but adding it to the beginning is `.prepend()` instead of sticking to convention and calling it `.prependChild()`

Comment: `append()` exists as well, works the same way as `prepend()`, but at the end

Comment: I also got confused when I saw these questions asking about implementing `prepend` while I found it's already been that. :( Ok, it didn't exist in the past.

Comment: @Marquizzo, Why not use `append`? For backcompat, obviously `appendChild` couldn't just be removed.

Answer (score 140):

## 2017 version

You can use

```
targetElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', newFirstElement)
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) :

> The insertAdjacentElement() method inserts a given element node at a given position relative to the element it is invoked upon.
>
> **position**
> A DOMString representing the position relative to the element; must be one of the following strings:
> `beforebegin`: Before the element itself.
> `afterbegin`: Just inside the element, before its first child.
> `beforeend`: Just inside the element, after its last child.
> `afterend`: After the element itself.
>
> **element**
> The element to be inserted into the tree.

In the family of `insertAdjacent` there is the sibling methods:

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','htmlText')`
```

That can inject html string directly, like `innerHTML` but without override everything, so you can use it as a mini-template Engin and jump the oppressive process of `document.createElement` and even build a whole component with string manipulation process

`element.insertAdjacentText` for inject sanitize string into element . no more `encode/decode`

Comment: great suggestion but why "back to 2017", this is a standard method even on ie8

Comment: thanks. and another thank for your insight.  title is for helping people distinguish quickly that is new answer

Comment: What if element = document.importNode(documentfragment, true)?

Comment: that return `element` typeof `document-fragment` that not have `insertAdjacent...()`. until we have a better answer your best guess is to append the `fragment` to a `div` . make your dom manipulation and then use `Range.selectNodeContents()` and `Range.extractContents()` to get back a fragment

Comment: where 'element' is the element in which you want to add, and 'element' is the element you want to add ;)

Answer (score 15):

You can implement it directly i all your window html elements.
Like this :

```
HTMLElement.prototype.appendFirst = function(childNode) {
    if (this.firstChild) {
        this.insertBefore(childNode, this.firstChild);
    }
    else {
        this.appendChild(childNode);
    }
};
```

Comment: `prepend` is the vanilla JS equivalent, without needing a prototype. It will be standard in ES7, and you should use if possible for your application

Comment: @Gibolt - DOM API methods have nothing to do with ECMAScript versions.

Comment: yorg - Just FYI, it's fine to pass `null` as the reference element in `insertBefore`, no need for your branch above.

Answer (score 8):

Accepted answer refactored into a function:

```
function prependChild(parentEle, newFirstChildEle) {
    parentEle.insertBefore(newFirstChildEle, parentEle.firstChild)
}
```

Comment: +1 for using parent child relationship. Accepted answer lacks that. I need to know what `eElement` is for it to make sense. And for that, I need to read the question. Most of the time, I just check the title and go directly to the answer, ignoring the question details.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I have misunderstood:

```
$("e").prepend("<yourelem>Text</yourelem>");
```

Or

```
$("<yourelem>Text</yourelem>").prependTo("e");
```

Although it sounds like from your description that there is some condition attached, so

```
if (SomeCondition){
    $("e").prepend("<yourelem>Text</yourelem>");
}
else{
    $("e").append("<yourelem>Text</yourelem>");
}
```

Comment: +1 for the $ version! I'm writing a jQuery extend func, so i'll use the native version whenever I can for performance reasons, but this is perfect!

Comment: Na, he's looking for JavaScript, not jquery.

Comment: @vinyll The jQuery tag has been there since the first revision, so that is highly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [.prepend](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend) function in jQuery. Example code:

```
$("#E").prepend("<p>Code goes here, yo!</p>");
```

Comment: You guys are fast! I'm sorry, I think I was misunderstood. 

element e 
        |- child-el_1
        |- child-el_2
        |- child-el_3

And then comes child-el_4 ... which needs to be fit as first child. 

prepend would put child-el_4 before [b]e[/b], am I wrong and tired or what?

Answer (score 0):

I created this prototype to prepend elements to parent element.

```
Node.prototype.prependChild = function (child: Node) {
    this.insertBefore(child, this.firstChild);
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newItem = document.createElement("LI");       // Create a <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");  // Create a text node
newItem.appendChild(textnode);                    // Append the text to <li>

var list = document.getElementById("myList");    // Get the <ul> element to insert a new node
list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);  // Insert <li> before the first child of <ul>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp