# Adding items to the top of the list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How could I specify that the items in this `function` should be added to the top of the list? At the moment it adds items to the bottom.

Here is the function itself:

```
function listFiller() {
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(guessedWord));
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" - "));
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(seconds));
    list.appendChild(entry);
}
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007357/how-to-set-dom-element-as-the-first-child).

Comment: Hope helps someone. Adding items to the top of list. Add new items to before current ; new.innerHTML = willaddelements.outerHTML + currentelements.outerHTML;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list.insertBefore(entry, list.firstChild);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore

Comment: @Phil I delete it to make you in peace :)

Answer (score 0):

`.appendChild()` will add the element to the last, if you want to prepend any element, you can use [**`.insertBefore()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

Incase jQuery, then [**`.prepend()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)