# Reverse the order of elements added to DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am making a game in JavaScript, and need an event log. If i attack, it tells me if i hit or i miss. Here is my code:

```
function eventlogshow (text){
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(text);
    para.appendChild(node);

    var element = document.getElementById("eventlog");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
```

It lists the most recent event on the bottom, with the oldest on top. How do i reverse that?
I would like it to show the most recent event on the top.

Comment: You should prepend instead of append the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update (Jan 2024):

[`Element.prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) is a method that is available in all mainstream browsers released 2018 and afterwards:

```
function eventlogshow (text){
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(text);

    para.appendChild(node);

    var element = document.getElementById("eventlog");
    element.prepend(para);
}
```

### Original answer (May 2014):

Prepend the child element instead. Since there is no `prependChild()` function, you need to "insert it before the first child":

```
function eventlogshow (text){
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(text);
    
    para.appendChild(node);

    var element = document.getElementById("eventlog");
    element.insertBefore(para, element.firstChild);
}
```

A similar question has been asked here: [How to set DOM element as first child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2007357/404623).

Read more about [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild) and [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2023, you can now do this with prepend()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend

Answer (score 1):

`appendChild` adds a node as a *last* child. You want to insert before the first node:

```
element.insertBefore(para, element.childNodes[0]);
```