# How to insert couple HTML elements before first child

Tags: javascript, html, css

F.e.

```
const logTable = document.getElementById("logs");
const newLog = document.createElement("tr");
const logValue = document.createElement("td");
logValue.innerHTML = "log";
logTable.appendChild(newLog);
newLog.appendChild(logValue + 1);
newLog.appendChild(logValue + 2);
newLog.appendChild(logValue + 3);
```

in HTML page it displays like this:
log1
log2
log3
but how can i insert this elements in reverse order:
log3
log2
log1
Without using

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

Comment: I think this question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749464/reverse-the-order-of-elements-added-to-dom-with-javascript/23749509

Comment: oh thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepend() instead of appendChild()

reference:
[JS Prepend()](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-prepend/)

Answer (score 0):

You could `prepend` the `<tr>` to the `<tbody>` of the `<table>`.

I added a `logMessage` function, because your current code could not produce your example output.

```js
const logTable = document.querySelector("#logs tbody");

const logMessage = (message) => {
  const
    newLog = document.createElement("tr"),
    logValue = document.createElement("td");
  logValue.textContent = message;
  newLog.append(logValue);
  logTable.prepend(newLog);
};

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  logMessage(`log${i + 1}`);
}
```

```css
#logs tbody {
  counter-reset: line-number;
}

#logs tbody tr {
  counter-increment: line-number;
}

#logs tbody tr:before {
  content: counter(line-number)" => "
}
```

```html
<table id="logs">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```