# Prepend/Append columns at beginning of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I prepend/append columns at beginning/end of my html table after exited with `</table>`markup?

(when before hitting the `</table>` mark)

- `<tr>` naturally appends rows
- `<td>` naturally appends cols/cells to the row

Javasript has a way of catching the table afterwards and modify the table: E.g. `table.insertRow()` with some functionality on where to insert the row.
Also, a kind of `table.prepend()` function exists, but which I cant really get working.

My table is horizontally scrollable, so I want to load more data (more columns) when user scrolls all the way to the end, both left and right. I have a way of detecting this but it's the action afterwards I'm having difficulties with.

Isn't there a `table.insertColumn(hereOrThere)`somewhere... hidden? ;)

Comment: this will solve it for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007357/how-to-set-dom-element-as-the-first-child. You just have to create your new row and then do .insertBefore the firstchild. Details on that link ...

Comment: `insertBefore` is a good idea but a better one could be a `<tr>` element specific method to insert a cell at a specific index that you prefer. Enter... [`HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) where you can specifiy the index of the cell as an argument like `rows.forEach(tr => tr.inserCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode('New cell'));`

Comment: @Redu that is indeed a cool way to do it.

Comment: Tnx guys. I'm don't really see a practical way for me to implement  @(82Tuskers) suggestions. But just quickly tried out @Redu 's suggestion with .insertCell() and it works!!! I'm gonna implement it and see how it handles reality ;)

Comment: Though I followed the example in @Redu 's link and not his javascript hack in the comment! (What is `rows`? the row element? then what is `tr`?

Comment: `rows` is just a nodeList of `<tr>` tagged nodes within a `<table>`. Such as when you do like `rows = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr")` where `"myTable"` is the `id` of the subject table like `< table id ="myTable">`

Comment: @Redu Aah good. Got it!

Comment: @Redu but man, put ur comment in an answer. Easier for others to find..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no built in way to prepend a column but you can do it by looping over all the rows, and preprending a cell to each row

```
function prependColumn(column) {
  $('tr').each((i, tr) => {
    $(tr).prepend('<td>' + column[i] + '</td>')
  })
}

prependColumn(['cell0','cell1', 'cell2', 'cell3'])
```

Comment: But ... I dont get it. If I've already drawn my table.. and execute this function.. where will the cell end up?

Comment: aha... 'tr' is the row id?...or tr?

Comment: can you clarify these comments? I don't understand your question

Comment: Is 'tr' the selector id in my <tr id = "id" >?  Like the node list of all my tr's?

Comment: the `$('tr')` selector is an element selector, not id. It will select all the table rows and add a `td` element in each row