# Is it possible to replace an HTML table td element with another td element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The reason I want to do this is because I am having trouble changing the classes of td elements in certain browsers. I am wondering if it is possible to simply replace the entire element, caveats, code, and suggestions are all appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace Dom element in place using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript)

Comment: You can use DOM methods as well as Table methods. You should not use innerHTML, there are some bugs. But it still should be easier to change classList / className.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace a table cell with another table cell just like any other element:

```
var td = <reference to td element>;
var newTd = document.createElement('td');
td.parentNode.replaceChild(newTd, td);
```

If you just want to add or assign a new class value, see qwertymk's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to easy remove some tds and replace them with new tds, i.e.:

```
$("td").remove();
$("tr").append("HTML CODE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `td.className += ' newClass'` to add a class or `td.className = 'newClass'` to assign it just one class?

Comment: I was using `td.className = 'newClass'`. Will using `td.className += 'newClass'` result in a td element that has multiple classes?

Comment: If you put a space before *newClass*, yes. i.e. ` newClass`. The class property is a space-separated list of values, so you need a space betwen each one.