# Javascript - replace an input type button with existing one

Tags: javascript, dom

I have input type submit defined inside a form. After some event, I need to replace this button with another button which is already defined hidden in my page. How can I do this in Javascript?

By replace, I mean, say, I have `btn1` and `btn2`. `btn1` is inside `form1`. After an event, `btn1` should be replaced with `btn2`, so after the replacement, `btn2` should be part of the `form1` and not `btn1`. And yes, the buttons should do their replacement inside a form tag.

I tried gooogling ofcourse but I can't find the right words maybe?

I need to make it work in IE8.

**Note : No JQuery please.**

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript `btn1.parentNode.replaceChild(btn2,btn1)`

Comment: Please post your code so far. What have you tried other than Googling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var firstbtn = document.getElementById("btn1");
var secondbtn = document.getElementById("btn2");
firstbtn.parentNode.replaceChild(secondbtn, firstbtn);
```