# Replacing original div with same ID: replaceChild() not giving correct results

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code that works but isn't very practical:

```
var blank1 = document.getElementById("blank1");
var this_image_filename = "/rgsi/images/poi-" + image_id + "-1--4.jpg";
blank1.innerHTML = "<div id='blank1' onclick=displayImg('" + this_image_filename + "') >1</div>";
```

The issue with this is that if you use inspect element in Chrome you get:

```
<div id="blank1">
    <div id="blank1" onclick="displayImg('/rgsi/images/poi-64-1--4.jpg')">1</div>
</div>
```

which is not good at all.

I attempted to use replaceChild() as listed in this question here:

[How to replace DOM element in place using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript)

but I keep getting:

*Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.*

**So the question is: what is the simplest way to correctly do this?**

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: If you're only changing an attribute, why replace the entire element ?

Comment: I don't see any `replaceChild` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You recreate your element inside itself.

I suppose you meant to do the following:

```
var blank1 = document.getElementById("blank1");
var this_image_filename = "/rgsi/images/poi-" + image_id + "-1--4.jpg";
blank1.onclick = function() { displayImg( this_image_filename ); }
blank1.innerHTML = "1";
```

Comment: Why is this better? Please elaborate on your solution.

Comment: @FelixKling I suppose this is what he meant to do. Not creating a div element, creating another div inside with the onclick function and same id..

Comment: I understand that. But it might be good if you just explained, that instead of adding a new child, you just modify the existing element. It might be obvious for us that that this is what happens, but not necessarily for less experienced developers.

Answer (score 0):

You must use UNIQUE id..

```
var blank1 = document.getElementById("blank1");
var this_image_filename = "/rgsi/images/poi-" + image_id + "-1--4.jpg";
blank1.innerHTML = "<div id='blank1_small' onclick=displayImg('" + this_image_filename + "') >1</div>";
```

And the html...

```
<div id="blank1">
        <div id="blank1_small" onclick="displayImg('/rgsi/images/poi-64-1--4.jpg')">1</div>
</div>
```

this could be right, but as @adeneo says, for change just one attribute, you can set this in JS

Comment: Right, understood, but doing `document.getElementById("blank1").onclick = displayImg('" + this_image_filename + "');` does not return the correct results. And the biggest thing is I don't want to create a new ID (idk if this is necessaribly bad or overbearing though).

Comment: don't set the onclick in the html, but set it at the document.load, in JS

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
document.getElementById("blank1").onclick = function() {
    var this_image_filename = "/rgsi/images/poi-" + image_id + "-1--4.jpg";
    displayImg(this_image_filename);          
}
```