# How to replace element with text using JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So assuming I had this:

```
<span id="foo">bar</span>
```

I want to replace it with this:

```
bar
```

In other words, I want to remove the span from the DOM, and insert its contents in its place.

How can I achieve this, using code as minimal as possible? I want to use pure JavaScript, but jQuery's fine as well.

Thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan not quite a duplicate, but close. The OP includes jQuery, and as my answer shows, there is another way ( *with* jQuery )

Comment: Change the link in the answer with a textnode and it is, as my answer shows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `.replaceWith` ...

```
$( "#foo" ).replaceWith( "bar" );
```

jQuery: [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) »

Answer (score 8):

Plain JS using a textNode:

```
var span = document.getElementById("foo");
span.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("bar"), span);
```

Comment: *this* is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript

Comment: What are you saying? My answer is plain JS as requested. jQuery was ok too

Comment: I am saying your answer is the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript

Comment: My answer is the modified answer using textnode. It was written by hand and is using the same syntax, but is answered since the answer in the duplicate (which I linked to) was not using a textnode as you mentioned in the comment to my duplicate link

Answer (score 4):

use `.unwrap()`:

```
$("#foo").contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: after replacing the contents with "bar"

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can replace the element with it's contents using `replaceWith` method and `childNode` property, this will work in case that your element has more than one descendant Node:

```
$('#foo').replaceWith(function() {
   return this.childNodes;
});
```

Using pure JavaScript something like the following should work:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

while(foo.childNodes.length)
   foo.parentNode.insertBefore(foo.childNodes[0], foo);

foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mM54V/