# Is there something like the swift optional chaining in javascript?

Tags: javascript, swift, option-type

I've been doing a lot of code likes this in javascript

`if (params && params.profile && params.profile.address && params.profile.address.default)`

where I have to check for each optional, it gets pretty tedious.  Is there a better way in javascript that's similar to how swift would deal with optionals, e.g.

`if let checked = params?.profile?.address?.default?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key ?

Comment: It's coming! It's been moved to Stage 3 (as of late July 2019) https://twitter.com/drosenwasser/status/1154456633642119168

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such operator in native JS.

However, there is a Babel plugin that will accomplish that, please check https://github.com/davidyaha/ecmascript-optionals-proposal

Also, please refer to [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015/41897688#41897688) for more references

Answer (score 10):

[Optional chaining has now been added to the language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) using the same `?.` syntax as Swift, so I recommend doing it that way unless you need to support older browser versions.

If you do, I've written a function that handles this:

```
function getSafe (func) {
    try {
        return func()
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
            return undefined
        } else {
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
if (getSafe(() => params.profile.address.default))
```

This works because by wrapping it in an anonymous function, it isn't evaluated until the try/catch block, which will then catch the error and return `undefined` if any of the parent properties are undefined.

Checking whether `e` is a `TypeError` prevents it from swallowing any other errors the function might throw so those can still be handled as needed. If you want it to just return `undefined` on any error, you can remove that part:

```
function getSafeNoErrors (func) {
    try {
        return func()
    } catch {
        return undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## 2020 Answer, It Exists!!!

You can now directly use `?.` (Optional Chaining) inline to safely test for existence. All modern browsers support it.

If a property exists, `?.` proceeds to the next check, or returns the valid value. Any failure will immediately short-circuit and return `undefined`.

```
const example = {a: ["first", {b:3}, false]}

example?.a  // ["first", {b:3}, false]
example?.b  // undefined

// Dynamic properties ?.[]
example?.a?.[0]     // "first"
example?.a?.[1]?.a  // undefined
example?.a?.[1]?.b  // 3

// Functions ?.()
null?.()                // undefined
validFunction?.()       // result
(() => {return 1})?.()  // 1

// DOM Access
domElement?.parentElement?.children?.[3]?.nextElementSibling
```

If you do not check a case, the left-side property must exist. If not, it will throw an exception.

```
example?.First         // undefined
example?.First.Second  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Second' of undefined
```

[`?.` Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining) - 82%, Oct 2020

[Node Support](https://medium.com/@nodejs/node-js-version-14-available-now-8170d384567e) - 14+

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 1):

```
function optionalChaining(obj, chain) {
  return chain
    .split('.')
    .reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc ? acc[val] : undefined;
    }, obj);
}

var user = {
 address: {
  street: 'No.969 West WenYi Road',
},
 a: { b: { c: 2 } },
}

optionalChaining(user, 'address.street'); // 'No.969 West WenYi Road'
optionalChaining(user, 'a.b.c') // 2
```

The function can simulate optional chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's one.
In ES2020 they've added optional chaining and optional function invocation.

```js
   const person = {
        name: "Someone",
        age: 28
    }
    console.log(person?.name) // "Someone"
    console.log(person?.["age"]) // 28
    person?.getAge?.() //   no errors, just undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer above you can now install this babel plugin straight from NPM:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining

```
obj?.prop       // optional static property access
obj?.[expr]     // optional dynamic property access
func?.(...args) // optional function or method call
```

**Notes:**

In order to allow foo?.3:0 to be parsed as foo ? .3 : 0 (as required for backward compatibility), a simple lookahead is added at the level of the lexical grammar, so that the sequence of characters ?. is not interpreted as a single token in that situation (the ?. token must not be immediately followed by a decimal digit).

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Also worth checking out:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing

https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator