# In ES2015 is there a way to directly access object properties without checking for undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES5 whenever I want to get some property I need to first check that it exists like this:

```
if (typeof floob.flib !== 'undefined') {
    // do something
}
```

even worse is that for nested properties you have to manually check for the existence of every property down the dotted path.

Is there a better way to do this in ES2015?

Comment: "In ES5 whenever I want to get some property I need to first check that it exists" --- no you don't need that. Btw, to check if the property is there - there is an `in` operator. Your check is prone to false negatives.

Comment: @zerkms can you please expand on how the "in" operator can be used to tell me if a nested attribute exists on an object?

Comment: The same way your `typeof` would do - recursively.

Comment: @zerkms without wanting to criticise, but I think the idea of StackOverflow is to give answers that are a full explanation rather than terse bullet points.

Comment: That is the very reason I haven't posted an answer but a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-in-es6-es2015

Answer (score 2):

1. If it is just a single depth property name - you don't need `typeof`, you may just compare the value with `undefined`.
2. Your solution is prone to false negatives: it may think there is no a property with a given name, while there is one. Example: `var o = { foo: undefined };`
3. If you need to check if the path exists in the nested objects - you still need to implement recursion/loop/or use any library that does either for you.
4. ES2015 did not bring anything new to solve this problem easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `lodash` available, you can use `_.get(obj, path, defaultValue)` (https://lodash.com/docs#get)

Answer (score -1):

By using `typeof`,

```
typeof floob.flib === 'undefined'
```

equals to,

```
floob.flib === undefined
```

I assume you want to check whether `floob.flib` has a value, and if it does, you want to perform an operation with it.

However, in JS, there's almost simpler way to achieve this.

**E.g.**

```
if (floob.flib) {
   // 'floob.flib' is NOT 'null', 'empty string', '0', false or 'undefined'
}
```

This also works well if you want to assign variable with ternary ( `?:` ) operators.

```
var str = floob.flib ? 'exists' : 'does not exist';
```

Or even using logical OR ( `||` )

```
var str = floob.flib || '<= either null, empty, false, 0 or undefined';
```

*Note that unless `floob.flib` does not produce `ReferenceError` exception, the code above should work just fine.*

Comment: `'floob.flib' is NOT 'null', 'empty string', or 'undefined'` should include `false`.

Comment: @torazaburo Lol.. Yes that should include too.. with `0` also.. Thanks for pointing that out..