# Existential operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, existential-operator

I have a large json object.  I need to access `x = a.b.c.d.e.f.g`.  However `b` (or `c`, `d`, `e`...) can be undefined.  This data structure is being imported from somewhere else.

Is there a way to try to get to assign `x` with `null` or `undefined` without throwing an error?

Comment: There is a proposal at stage 1 (there is a Babel plugin, though) https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining | Also, duplicate: [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015/41897688)

Answer (score 7):

## Update

Optional chaining is now part of the ECMAScript spec and can be used on most javascript clients (browsers, node.js, etc)

```js
x = a.b?.c?.d?.e?.f?.g
```

To use a default value if the access fails you can use the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
x = a.b?.c?.d?.e?.f?.g ?? 'my default value'
```

### original answer (2017)

The easiest way is to use `try catch`

```
try {
  x = a.b.c.d.e.f.g
} catch(e) {
  x = undefined;
}
```

There is a proposal for this called `optional chaining` you can check it here: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

```
x = a.b?.c?.d?.e?.f?.g
```

If you are using a transpiler you'll be able to use it, however its still in the very early stages and might not be accepted to be supported in the spec

Answer (score 4):

There are some proposals to solve this ( syntactic sugar missing) problem. Hopefully somewhen we may do this:

```
let x = a?.b?.c?.d?.e;
```

However, until then we need to fall back to objects if the variable is undefined:

```
var x =( ( ( ( (a || {}).b || {} ) || {} ).c || {} ).d || {}).e;
```

I admit that this is quite ugly. Maybe object destructuring is more beautiful:

```
let ({ 
   b: { 
     c: { 
       d: { e:x } = {}
     } = {}
   } = {}
}) = a;
```