# Can we specify a generic getter on an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, getter

I **want to do**:

`properties.email.value` without triggering an error like: `Can't read 'value' of 'undefined'`

However, I **don't want to do**:

`properties.email && properties.email.value` and I don't want to use an helper, something like: `get(properties, 'email.value')`.

---

I really want to keep the syntax `properties.email.value`

I can solve this by doing:

```
Object.defineProperty(properties, 'email', {
 get: () => properties.email && properties.email.value,
 enumerable: true,
 configurable: true
});
```

Now the `getter` is in charge of doing my safety check. Perfect.

But I also want to be able to do `properties.name.value` safely.
But as the `properties` object comes from the API (json), I don't know the full list of `properties` possible.

So, is there a way to use this "magical" `get` syntax for any prop access like: `properties[ANYTHING].value` ?

Comment: I think the answer is `NO`. Because `properties[ANYTHING]` will return `undefined`. and `undefined` has no property.

Comment: Yes I agree. That's why I wanted to know if there was a way to use the `Object.defineProperty` util and set a `get` method on `any` properties. But I think we can do this only with the properties already present in the object itself. There is no magical `getter` I think.

Comment: you could use a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: If you're open to use lodash, [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) is your bet.

Comment: @NinaScholz if you create an answer to this question I'll vote for you as being the answer. I have to give it a deeper look, but it seems like exactly what I'm asking for! Thanks! :D

Comment: Thanks @31piy that's a valid way, true, but as I mentioned: I don't want to use helpers like `get(properties, 'email.value')`. thanks

Comment: The feature is often referred as 'null propagation', here's a good thread on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015

Comment: what about the confusing `value` property?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "confusing `value`", but the idea is that this API returns a `value` and `title` for each prop (so it can be rendered in a form (as input label and value)

Comment: @Simple.Js I like it a lot as well, thanks for sharing!

Comment: i mean your set sets `email`, not `value`. email is first an object, later a string.

Comment: Right, good catch. I just typed my example quickly to make my point, but you're correct. I removed it for now. (question edited)

Comment: I've edited the answer. Hope this answer is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I've got something like this.

But you must create `properties` that way.

Hope this help :)

```js
var properties = {
  phone : {
    value: "123456789"
  }  
}

var handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    return target.hasOwnProperty(name) ? target[name] : {};
  }
};

var new_properties = new Proxy(properties, handler);

console.log("phone.value = " + new_properties.phone.value);

console.log("email.value = " + new_properties.email.value);

new_properties.email = {
  value: 1
};

console.log("email.value after assign = " + new_properties.email.value);
```

The document reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

**Edited**

Even if the original `properties` object is unknown, this kind of usage works as well.

Comment: I choose this one as the valid answer because it fits perfectly the requirements I asked. But, to be honest, all credits goes to @NinaScholz

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and get known properties and a custom result for unknow properties.

For changing properties, you could take the same approach and set the value.

```js
var properties = { email: { value: 'foo@example.com' } },
    proxy = new Proxy(
        properties,
        {
            get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                if (prop in target) {
                    return target[prop] && target[prop].value
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            },
            set: function(target, prop, value) {
                if (prop in target) {
                    target[prop].value = value;
                } else {
                    target[prop] = { value };
                }
            }
        }
    );

console.log(proxy.email);
console.log(proxy.bar);

proxy.email = '41';
console.log(proxy.email);
```

Comment: Your answer works, although I still want to be able to make my calls like: `proxy.email.value` and `proxy.email.title`. I simply have to udpate your `get` method with: `return target[prop] || {}`

Comment: for inner objects, you could use another proxy.

Comment: In the end I just end up doing:
    `const proxy = new Proxy(properties, {
      get: (target, prop) => (prop in target) ? target[prop] : {},
    })`

This way any `proxy.email.value` or `proxy.anything.value` won't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I'm doing this...

```
var wordlength = 7;
var alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
alphabet += alphabet.toUpperCase() + "0123456789_";
var alen = alphabet.length;
var buildWord = function(number){
    if(number===0){
        return '';
    }
    return alphabet[number%alen]+buildWord(Math.floor(number/alen));
};
var total = Math.pow(alen, wordlength);
for(var i = 1; i<total; i++){
    var w = buildWord(i);
    if(isNaN(w[0]) && Object.prototype[w]===undefined){
        Object.prototype[w]={};
    }
}
```

Comment: No.... It should do what they want. Although it doesn't support the $ sign and some other vars. Could add those in I guess.

Comment: Technically speaking, it answers the brief. They won't get any exceptions. It just won't be very useful either. It should be fairly clear this is not a serious answer anyway.