# How to reduce this if statement check in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shorthand

How can I reduce this if statement in JavaScript

```
if(obj.attributes && obj.attributes.email === 'test@test.com') { ... }
```

Comment: if it's possible that `obj.attributes` is undefined, you can't - well, you can use try/catch, but thta's probably MORE code

Comment: Frankly that looks fine to me as is, it's clear and concise already. Although fwiw you can use the shorter but arguably worse: `if ((obj.attributes || {}).email === "test@test.com") { ... }`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that check. One possible alternative is `if((obj.attributes || {email:''}).email === 'test@test.com') { ... }` but that looks worse.

Comment: There's no easy way to do it.  Workarounds exist, but they're only really worth it for longer chains - the way I usually do it would be about as long in this case anyway, and probably harder to read.

Comment: Related: [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015), which if we ever get optional chaining, you could use `obj.attributes?.email === ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line by it self is clear, however if you are looking a way to write less `&&` operator inside you can always put things outside of the comparison such as.

```
var attributes = obj.attributes || {};
if ( attributes.email === 'test@test.com' ) {
}
```

This makes sense if you need to make multiple checks instead of a single one, however if is a single comparison it seems like the code you already have is okay as you are making sure `attributes` is defined before accessing an `undefined` property.

On the other hand if you have support for ES 2015 you can destruct stuff like:

```
const { attributes = {} } = obj;
if ( attributes.email === 'test@test.com' ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable `get` function using `Array.reduce()`. The function parameters are a path, the object, and a defaultValue (default `defaultValue` is `undefined`). It will iterate the path, and try to extract the value, if it fails, it will return the `defaultValue`:

```js
const get = (path, obj, defaultValue) => obj ? 
  path.reduce((r, k) => r && typeof r === 'object' ? r[k] : defaultValue, obj) 
  : 
  defaultValue;

if(get(['attributes', 'email'], null) === 'test@test.com') { console.log(1) }
if(get(['attributes', 'email'], {}) === 'test@test.com') { console.log(2) }
if(get(['attributes', 'email'], { attributes: {} }) === 'test@test.com') { console.log(3) }
if(get(['attributes', 'email'], { attributes: { email: 'test@test.com' } }) === 'test@test.com') { console.log(4) }
```

There is a TC39 stage proposal called ["Optional Chaining for JavaScript"](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining). If it will make it's way to the language, it will add an the optional chaining operator - `?`. Now if `attributes` don't exist, it will return `undefined`.

**Example:** obj.attributes?.email

It's usable today via [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining.html).