# ES6/JS assign default value if array.find returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I set a default value to a variable if array.find returns 'undefined'.

Here's the line that's causing me issues. In some instances this variable will populate but in others, it won't and in that case, I want it to default to 0.

```
this.statistics.creditAmount = response.data.find(t => t.paymentType == 'RF' && t.status == 1).amount || 0;
```

Comment: You could do this: `(response.data.find(t => t.paymentType == 'RF' && t.status == 1) || { amount : 0 }).amount`. But an if-else or a ternary operator check is much more readable IMO

Comment: No point in creating a snippet that can't run.

Comment: That worked like a charm @adiga although it's not very readable. What are the double pipes doing exactly?

Comment: `(data.find(t => t.paymentType == 'RF' && t.status == 1) || { amount : 0 })` block first checks if there is value in the found object. If it is `undefined`, the OR operator will use the second object `{ amount : 0 }`. Then get the `amount` property from the object returned.

Answer (score 11):

I see this has been answered but I thought this could contribute

```
const { amount = 0 } = response.data.find(t => t.paymentType === 'RF' && t.status === 1) || {};
this.statistics.creditAmount = amount;
```

Or you could use a reducer:

```
  this.statistics.creditAmount = response.data.reduce((amt, t) => t.paymentType === 'RF' && t.status === 1 ? t.amount : amt, 0);
```

The reducer would use more clock cycles as it traverses the entire array, whereas `Array.prototype.find` stops once it reaches the first match. This may cause the results to vary as well, since the way that reducer is written it will take the *last* item from the array that matches.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your code is that you're accessing `.amount` of `undefined` for cases where `array.find` returns `undefined`. You can solve it by adding a guard:

```
const credit = response.data.find(t => 
  t.paymentType == 'RF' && t.status == 1);

this.statistics.creditAmount = credit ? credit.amount : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a closure and a destructuring with a default object/value.

```
const
    getAmount = ({ amount = 0 } = {}) => amount,
    credit = getAmount(response.data.find(t => t.paymentType == 'RF' && t.status == 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible overkill, but you could create and implement a reusable null propagation method.

```js
const response = {data: []};

const _try = (func, fallbackValue) => {
    try {
        var value = func();
        return (value === null || value === undefined) ? fallbackValue : value;
    } catch (e) {
        return fallbackValue;
    }
}


const result = _try(() => response.data.find(t => t.paymentType == 'RF' && t.status == 1).amount, 0);
console.log(result);
```

This was originally written by tocqueville as part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553572/2026606).