# I want to use the Babel plug-in: optional-chaining, but the vscode console prompted me incorrectly. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, babeljs

I created a new project with the create-react-app scaffold, and then I wanted to use the optional-chaining plug-in of babel. I installed the package according to the document and configured it, but vscode prompted grammatical errors. What can help me? please.

1. this is my [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYaDh.png).
2. this is the problem:
   [image]

Comment: Can you include your package.json in your question, rather than linking to an image?

Comment: I'm a new account. I don't have permission.

Comment: Copy out the text and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **CRA** there is probably no way instead of **ejecting** project and applying Babel presets manually (according to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4604).

However, if you are decided to use `eject` there should be able to add plugin to babel config which is described here https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining. Probably applying `stage-0` preset of Babel (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-0) can also be a solution.

Edit: see also [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015)

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is from Visual Studio Code's built-in JavaScript and/or TypeScript validator. In order to circumvent this, add this to your vscode `settings.json` file:

`"javascript.validate.enable": false`

Additionally you can disable the built-in TypeScript validator like this:

`"typescript.validate.enable": false`

Once those are disabled, eslint will take over and show you the proper errors when applicable.