# How to print only first element from JSON Array in ReactJs?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I have the following JSON Array data from which I want to print Charlie. How to do it?

```
[ [ {
"ID": 1,
"Name" :"David"
},{
"ID": 2,
"Name" :"Antony"
}],[{
"ID": 1,
"Name" :"Bob"
},{
"ID": 2,
"Name" :"Charlie"
} ] ]
```

Comment: what error does it gives, how are you printing ?? can you post how you are printing ?

Comment: {PostData.map((group, index)=>{
return <p>{group.Name}</p>

This prints all the names, but I want to print only the first or second name

Comment: If you are reading this array asynchronous than this can be empty so first check if that has at least one item then try to access with data[0]

Comment: I have this array in json file.

Comment: If you only want the first one, then don't map the whole array. Just take the first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using `{PostData.map((group, index)=>{ return <p>{group.Name}</p>`, since you are using `map` here `PostData[0].Name` will throw error inside `map()`, because you are iterating array with `map()`.

Since you only need first item, you can simply use `<p>PostData[0].Name</p>`

```js
var data = [{
"ID": 1,
"Name" :"David",
},  {
"ID": 2,
"Name" :"Antony",
}];

console.log(data[0].Name)
```

Comment: This way, it printed the same name twice.

Comment: @AnmolKhanna  are you using like this `{PostData.map((group, index)=>{ return <p>{postData[0].Name}</p> }` ??

Comment: Yes, exactly this way.

Comment: thats why its printing twice, dont use `.map()`, use like `{PostData && <p>{PostData[0].Name}</p>}`

Comment: PostData((group, index)=>{

 return <p>{PostData[0].Name}</p> 

This gave an error

Comment: can you follow what I posted before

Comment: Is there a way I can find the length of the array, as in how many sets of id and name do I have in the array? I am absolutely new on react..

Comment: To get the array length, you can use `array.length`, you can refer https://javascript.info/array  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array for more info

Answer (score 2):

```
var response= [{
"ID": 1,
"Name" :"David",
},  {
"ID": 2,
"Name" :"Antony",
}];
```

`console.log(response[0].Name)` will give you first element of Array and return data with Key 'Name'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above and although the **console.log(data[0].Name)** would work to test the value, when it came to inserting the chosen value within the returned html code, I needed to use the code below. The reason is when we return the rows of data, only one row is valid and we need to use the "?" condition, as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824031/7496293 to exclude all the other cases and not have your code break:

```
{data[0]?.Name}
```