# What does question mark (?) after class name mean when calling class methods in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, conditional-operator

I have a TypeScript code snippet that contains the following statement `row?.delete();`.

I was wondering what does the question mark symbolize?

What would happen in case row was null?

Thanks!

Comment: Also: [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32139078)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operator is called optional chaining. What it does is first checks if the row is defined and then tries to access the delete.

In case row is null this `row?.delete()` will just return undefined.If you used it without this operator like `row.delete()` and row was null you would get `Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined`.

For more details and examples you can check here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html