# using console?.log(69) instead console.log(69) not getting any error why?

Tags: javascript

After running `console.log(69)` and `console?.log(69)` getting `69` as output. What is use of `'?'` ?

Comment: A dupe that points to a dupe that points to a dupe...

Comment: This is the final target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015 Let me check if I can get someone with a golden hammer

Comment: The '?' operator checks if the object exists, and only if it is true he continues to the next property.    
In this case - the 'console' object always exists so the 'log' property always going to work. console?.log(69) is shorter syntax to: if(console) console.log(69)