# Cannot read property in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In App.js

```js
export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.github.com/users/deepakranga1801")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(setData);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Card item={data} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

In Card.js

```js
function Card(props) {
    return (
        <div><h1>{props.item.name}</h1></div>
    );
}
```

I'm trying to pass data fetch from API from `app.js` to `card.js` but through

> TypeError Cannot read property 'name' of null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is because the first time when the `item` is passed then it would be `null` and it doesn't have property `name` on it. So either you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or logical AND

**1)** Just use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator in JSX

```
{props.item?.name}
```

**2)** Logical AND

```
<h1>{props.item && props.item.name}</h1>
```

CODE

```
export default function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.item?.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. it worked! & understood where I was wrong

Comment: Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to the async nature of making an API request. The `Card` component is already rendered, before the response from the API. The first time it runs, `props.item` doesn't exist, therefore it throws an error. You can prevent this from happening by using `props?.item?.name`. You can see a decent explanation of the optional properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015)