# Why some using '?.' to access the JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json

Example:

```
const genre = {
  "action": {
    "rating": "8",
    "movie": "John Wick"
  },
  "romance": {
    "rating": "6.5",
    "movie": "The Girl Next door"
  }
}
```

For accessing the movies based on the 'Genre' we can use `genre.action`

But why `genre?.action` also works. Can anyone explain I've seen people use this '?.' to access the JSON objects.

Thanks:)

Comment: Voting to close - duplicate of [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is call [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)  which allows to access the key of the nested object only if the key is not nullish or undefined

```js
const genre = {
  "action": {
    "rating": "8",
    "movie": "John Wick"
  },
  "romance": {
    "rating": "6.5",
    "movie": "The Girl Next door"
  }
}

console.log(genre.action?.rating);
console.log(genre.someKey?.someKey)
```

Comment: And this should be a close vote and not an answer...