# typescript don't warn about a potentially undefined array?

Tags: typescript

I have a question about how could I leverage typescript to warn about an array that could cause a run time error ? I have the following code I usually use a question mark after the array .. but should typescript know that this might cause a runtime error ?

```js
// cause run time erorr.. 
context.arr[props.id].includes(select)
// no run time erorr
context.arr[props.id]?.includes(select)
```

Comment: If it's the `context.arr[props.id]` that might be undefined, that's just fine

Comment: @CertainPerformance it is created after an action... but the function that does the check runs as well , but shouldn't typescript be warning about this ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance it possible to warn about `context.arr[props.id]` potentially undefined by enabling `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`. It can introduce a lot of noise in existing code base, but still possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?.` is [optional chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015), which will properly chain with what follows *if* the expression on the left-hand side is defined (not undefined/null), and will evaluate to `undefined` otherwise:

```
context.arr[props.id]?.includes(select)

// if context.arr[props.id] is undefined/null, equivalent to:
undefined
// (does not throw an error)


// if context.arr[props.id] is  notundefined/null, equivalent to:
context.arr[props.id].includes(select)
```

So, as long as TypeScript can see that, when `context.arr[props.id]` isn't undefined/null, it'll be an array, that statement is perfectly type-safe. (though, TypeScript [has problems](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) with `.includes`, but that's another issue)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the desired behavior by turning on [Checked Indexed Accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) (available since 4.1 version). Under this mode, indexed access is considered potentially undefined. To enable it - set `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) to `true`.

```
const arr = ['foo', 'bar']

// Expect error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
arr[1].includes('test')

// OK
arr[1]?.includes('test')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgGYhJgGhkwCNFMBdAKCoHpaYBRADwAcBTYWdpEBALhgB5EgCtOsAJYQYrEBAiSSAGwCexAK5gAJu2ySw7bZgB0VRAnQBGCiYPBlG3RAAUmKO2iYAlDXrCAaXMkawoAfjswBydPNw8vbyA)

---

Comment: --- Perfect ---