# Undefined property on an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have a Typescript project in which I am reassigning variables depending on the value that the object contains.

What I am trying to do is define a variable from a property of the object, instead, if this property does not exist, a default value is established.

This is my Object:

```
interface InsParams {
  host?: string,
  country?: string,
  pageLimit?: number,
  pageOffset?: number,
  pageToken?: string
}

let dataObj: InsParams;
```

This is the variable I'm creating:

```
let limit: number = dataObj.pageLimit ? dataObj.pageLimit : 1000
```

This is the error it shows:

```
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined
```

**My problem:** I need if the property does not exist to assign another value to the limit variable, but it shows an error.

Comment: The issue isn't the property. The issue is that you haven't assigned **anything** to `dataObj`, so it has the value `undefined`, and you can't access any property on `undefined`.

Comment: Separately, `dataObj.pageLimit ? ` will test if `pageLimit` is [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), not whether it's not present. `0` is a falsy value, so if `0` is a potentially-valid value for `pageLimit`, that check would be incorrect. Instead you'd want `"pageLimit" in dataObj ?`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The object can come empty but I have to declare the variables, in case that property comes empty or does not exist I want to assign a default value to it, to avoid errors in the rest of the process

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015)

Comment: This runtime error could have been prevented by enabling the [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) compiler option and fixing the resulting compile errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue comes from `dataObj` being potentially undefined. In this case, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) + [null coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
let limit = dataObj?.pageLimit ?? 1000;
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can't seen to find the right issue: please close as duplicate if you can find it, thanks!

Comment: The type of the `dataObj` variable should be updated to `let dataObj: InsParams | undefined;`, so the compiler reports the original issue up front.

Comment: @JSONDerulo - For me, [it does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgM4AU5TgWw2QG8BYAKGWQAsB7DMAfgC5kGpQBzAGgqoVoBXcFACeLNmA4gefZAAc4nCABlg+YE1YhB+AEbRelBUogB5GDAwQtyHfsNzFygCq0A1hBAT2XCgF8KCgAbG2QAEzgwODM9ACtWdGxcAgwAbiDyULBkYPVNbV0DKGQAXgiomPiAOmdVfJzGCujYuNrTNQ0c1gBGAAYBoA).

Comment: I can't find a clean one! Nothing as clean as this. So there we are. :-) (I mean, it's probably *there*, but if neither of us can find it...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right, it's because of the `strictNullChecks` compiler option, which the OP seems to miss.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had not seen this way of accessing the data to check that it is undefined, it works well and I do not see a better way to assign empty property variables

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
let limit: number = dataObj?.pageLimit ? dataObj?.pageLimit : 1000;
```

Comment: This solution was posted several minutes ago (but with explanation). Please be sure not to accidentally duplicate answers that are already present. Also, rather than posting just code, please take the time to *explain* your answer -- what you did, and why you had to do it.