# performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit error in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, safari

I am trying to assign to a variable the value of performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit
But since it is not supported on Safari, I would like to assign to the same variable the value 0 when performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit doesn't work.

I am doing this:

```
(function () {
if (performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit !== undefined) {
var MAXmemoryAvailable = performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit; 
} else { 
var MAXmemoryAvailable = 0; }
})();
```

The problem is that on Safari it doesn't work and I have the error:
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit')

Any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) by adding `?`:

> The optional chaining (`?.`) operator accesses an object's property or calls a function. If the object accessed or function called using this operator is undefined or null, the expression short circuits and evaluates to undefined instead of throwing an error.

Example:

```js
(function () {
    if (performance?.memory?.jsHeapSizeLimit !== undefined) {
        var MAXmemoryAvailable = performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit; 
    } else { 
        var MAXmemoryAvailable = 0;
    }

    console.log(MAXmemoryAvailable);
})();
```

With Firefox, which doesn't support `performance.memory` (and consequently `performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit`), it shows `0`.