# Replace an element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blogger

How can I replace an element with Javascript in blogger? The element is a word in h2 post title. Example: Review | Armaggedon. I want to delete "Review |"
How would be a script for do that?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: document.getElementById("YOUR_H2_ID").innerText.replace("Review |", "")

Comment: Thank you. How I can made a Script with this? Sorry for the question I don't know nothing about JVScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace DOM element in place using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a javascript function (for example, see the function `updateTitle` below) and call that whenever needed (or just do the following where needed). In that function, get a reference to the element using [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Then using [string.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), update the property [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of that variable referencing the element.

In the example below, we call `updateTitle` when the button is clicked, but it could be called in other scenarios, e.g. after loading content asynchronously (e.g. with AJAX techniques), other user interaction, etc.

```js
function updateTitle() {
  var theTitle = document.getElementById('theTitle');
  theTitle.innerHTML = theTitle.innerHTML.replace('Review |','');
  }
```

```html
<h2 id="theTitle">Review | Armaggedon</h2>
<button onClick="updateTitle()">Update title</button>
```

Comment: So, how can I make this but with a class. (.post h1, for example)?

Comment: does your h1 have (only) an attribute `class="h1"`? if so, are there multiple elements with that classname and would you want to update more than one? if it is just one, then add the `id` attribute and use that