# How can I replace a element with another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="should_be_replaced">something</div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also I have a variable which is containing some HTML tags:

```
var str = "<b>title</b><p>sth <span>sss</span></p>";
```

Now I want to replace the content of variable above with `div.should_be_replaced` element. How can I do that?

This is expected result:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <b>title</b><p>sth <span>sss</span></p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.should_be_replaced').parentNode.innerHTML = str`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace DOM element in place using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$('.should_be_replaced').replaceWith(str);
```

```js
var str = "<b>title</b><p>sth <span>sss</span></p>";
$('.should_be_replaced').replaceWith(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="should_be_replaced">something</div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Without jQuery

```
document.querySelector('.should_be_replaced').outerHTML = str;
```

```js
var str = "<b>title</b><p>sth <span>sss</span></p>";
document.querySelector('.should_be_replaced').outerHTML = str;
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="should_be_replaced">something</div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this if you have jQuery:

```
var str = "<b>title</b><p>sth <span>sss</span></p>";
$(".should_be_replaced").parent().html(str);
```

or without jQuery

```
document.getElementsByClassName('should_be_replaced')[0].parentNode.inn‌​erHTML = str
```

Comment: Martin, be sure to include the **jQuery library** if you want to use this solution.

Comment: @NewToJS - Martin already tagget the question with jQuery, so he either tagged it incorrectly, or is using jQuery

Comment: Yes, jQuery is tagged in the question but if you look at the OP's source code, it doesn't have `jQuery` linked hence pointing out the use of jQuery in your solution... since you failed to do that.

Comment: jQuery and vanilla, covering both. Great answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

you can use direct html method for change content.

```
var str = "<b>title</b><p>sth <span>sss</span></p>";
    jQuery("section").html(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dmxk59gg/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div id="should_be_replaced" onclick="click()">something</div>
        </section>
     <script>
        function click() {
            var str = "<b>title</b><p>sth <span>sss</span></p>";
            document.getElementById("should_be_replaced").innerHTML = str;
        }
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do by jQuery.

```
var section = jQuery('section');
section.find('div').remove();
section.html(str);
```