# How can I change the login <li> with another css design, when the user log in in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, css

I made a `Navigation Bar` which contain a Login , so I want to change it with a `div` (contain image and user's name),  when the user log in !

NavBar :

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="axit-nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a> <button id="myButton">Create event</button></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a class="dsctv hidden-xs hidden-sm">events</a></li>
                <li><a class="dsctv hidden-xs hidden-sm">Login</a></li>
                <li><img alt="Logo brand Wevento" class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm" src="theme/img/logos/Logo%20White%20Blue.png" </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

PHPcode :

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Mail'])) {
     header('Location: admin/index.php');
}
include 'admin/init.php';    
// Check for ADMINS
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $mail= $_POST['mail'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $hashedPass= sha1($password);

    // check if the user exist in DB

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Mail, Password FROM admin WHERE Mail= ?  AND Password = ? ");
    $stmt->execute(array($mail, $hashedPass));
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($count > 0) {
        $_SESSION['Mail'] = $mail;

    } 
}
 ?>
```

Comment: [Refer this link. ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript) It is the same issue of DOM element replacement.

Comment: Navbar img tag not closed.

Comment: Thank you i didn't notice that, but it works ! weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a check to confirm if the session exists.
If yes, show the user name, if not, show the login link. Something like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="axit-nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a> <button id="myButton">Create event</button></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a class="dsctv hidden-xs hidden-sm">events</a></li>
        <?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) { ?>
        <li><a class="dsctv hidden-xs hidden-sm">Login</a></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a class="dsctv hidden-xs hidden-sm"><?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <li><img alt="Logo brand Wevento" class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm" src="theme/img/logos/Logo%20White%20Blue.png" </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Of course echo out the user name based on how you stored it in the session.

Comment: Thank you very muck that answer my question !

Answer (score -2):

If you are using jQuery, I think you can edit with `.css()` method.

Something like

```
$('your-element').click(function () {
 $(this).css('background', '#000');
};
```

jQuery .css() method documentation : http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but where should I place this code ? because I want to replace it when the user log in !

Comment: I honestly don't know, but try adding the <script> tag into your html code. If that doesn't work, then wait for someone to provide you a better answer.

Comment: Thank you anyway :)