# setting node.outerHTML does not do anything

Tags: javascript, html

In the [mozill api docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) for outerHTML is stated, that when seeting `outerHTML`:

> Replaces the element with the nodes generated by parsing the string content with the parent of element as the context node for the fragment parsing algorithm.

However, when I tried this in the console it didnt work:

```
var d = document.createElement('div')
d.outerHTML = '<p>Some Text</p>'
console.log(d) //<div>
```

Can someone explain to me why this isnt working as expected?

// EDIT: Accoring to comments I should append it to a rendering context. The following **still not** work for me:

```
var d = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(d)
d.outerHTML = '<p>Some Text</p>'
console.log(d) //<div>
```

// EDIT2: Looking at the generated source, the element indeed gets replaced. However, `d` is still a div. Well - thats confusing. Why is that so?

Comment: Because there is no parent element to provide a parsing context.

Comment: I thought that too, so I tried that example but with the additional line `document.body.appendChild(d)` - no difference

Comment: did you appendChild before you set outerHTML? - it works for me (Chrome) - https://jsfiddle.net/xhh7vgzb/

Comment: Using FF here. I append it directly after creation (edit: not working in chrome, too. Code: `var d = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(d);
d.outerHTML = '<p>Some Text</p>';
console.log(d); //<div>`

Comment: As the docs state: "Also, while the element will be replaced in the document, the variable whose outerHTML property was set will still hold a reference to the original element:"

Comment: guess reading is a useful skill - also in this case. Thanks @j08691. Post it as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Notes) has the answer as to why the div element gets replaced and `console.log(d)` refers to the original div and not the replaced content:

> ...while the element will be replaced in the document, the variable
>   whose outerHTML property was set will still hold a reference to the
>   original element...

Comment: To add, you may like to know: how to [`target.replaceWith(element)`] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript