# Change start tag and end tag separately

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the flowing:

```
<a href="#">something</a>
```

withthis:

```
(start-a)something(end-a)
```

I do not master the regex well, so the regex I have its just to change all tags completely.

```
string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"(start-a)");
```

Whats should I change in my regex for just replacing the first tag, and the other change to replace the ending tag?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use DOM methods instead of regex. [obligatory canonical link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)

Comment: @DanielBeck Could you please give me an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript

Comment: What is your real input?

Comment: @DanielBeck, well, such example is for changing from one tag to another. but I need to do it in a string not in DOM.

Comment: Are you doing this in a browser or in another environment like node.js?

Comment: Convert your string into a DOM object and work with that.  Seriously, regex is the wrong tool for manipulating HTML.

Comment: @revo The real input is a string (like shown) and the output a string too. Not for DOM.

Comment: Do you mean anchor tags with href value of `#` only?

Comment: @revo  string A = "<a href="#">something</a>" and I need B = "(start-a)something(end-a)"

Comment: Please show enough of your "*[mcve]*" code so that we have some chance of reproducing your problem, also: read the "*[ask]*" (and "['runnable snippet'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)") guidelines. Where is the input string coming from? When, or how, do you expect to encounter, and modify, it?

Comment: Okay then do `A.replace('<a href="#">', '(start-a)').replace('</a>', '(end-a)')`~

Comment: @revo, well, what if the case that href has not #? I need a general case for changing all

Comment: That's why I asked a question which you didn't answer. Your requirements are not clear. Which tags are allowed to be treated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find all the tags you wish to replace.
2. Create a new text node based on each tag.
3. Insert new node.
4. Delete old tag.

```js
// Find all tags to be replaced and put in an Array and loop through them
var tags = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a")).forEach(function(tag){
  // Find the parent element of the node
  var parent = tag.parentNode;
  
  // Create a new text node with the contents of the current element
  var replaceString = document.createTextNode("(start-a)" + tag.textContent + "(end-a)");
  
  // Insert the new text node where the current tag is
  parent.insertBefore(replaceString, tag);
  
  // Delete the old tag
  parent.removeChild(tag);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">something</a>
  <a href="#">something</a>
  <a href="#">something</a>
  <a href="#">something</a>
  <a href="#">something</a>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI can use `document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach` without slice.call

Comment: @charlietfl Actually, no, you can't [in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). (IE any, Android).

Comment: yup...figures with IE...always 3 steps behind although there is  polyfill for it