# how to change the heading level of an html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, element, html-heading

If I have something like:

```html
<h2> test text </h2>
```

How would I use JavaScript to make it so that the text is now within a paragraph tag:

```html
<p> test text </p>
```

I was thinking I could do something like:

```js
var text = ('h2').text();

('h2').replace('<p>' + text + '</p>');
```

But it did not quite work.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, you need `$` before the function calls...

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+replace+element+type) of [How to replace DOM element in place using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40444300/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla JS, select the element, create a `<p>` element, and use `replaceWith` to replace the `<h2>` with the new `<p>`:

```js
const h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = h2.textContent;
h2.replaceWith(p);

console.log(document.body.children[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<h2> test text </h2>
```

Comment: Just a note for others finding this -- while it will work in this specific case, it will fail for more complex HTML. Any attributes on the <h2> will be lost, and using textContent instead of innerHTML means that any elements within the <h2> will be ignored, only the plain text content will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to replace the tag name.

```js
// document.getElementById("93").outerHTML = document.getElementById("93").outerHTML.replace(/wns/g,"lmn")

const h2List = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for (let index = 0; index < h2List.length; index ++) {
  h2List[index].outerHTML = h2List[index].outerHTML.replace(/h2/g, 'p');
}
```

```html
<h2> test text </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `outerHTML` of the `h2` tag like this:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('h2');
el.outerHTML = '<p>' + el.innerHTML + '</p>';
```

```html
<h2>Test 01</h2>
```