# Append element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below HTML structure.

```
<div class="SomeClassName">
   <a href="https://abc.xyz">
      <span>
         <img id="SomeImgID1" />
      </span>
   </a>
   <a href="https://xyz.abc">
      <span>
         <img id="SomeImgID2" />
      </span>
   </a>
</div>
```

I want to append `<div>` tag before each `<img>` tag, how do I do it with pure javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace DOM element in place using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript)

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```js
let divElement=document.querySelection('div.someClass');
Array.from(divElement.querySelectionAll('img'))
.forEach(el=>divElement.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'),el));
```

Again, if you want to **wrap** `img` then you can use next snippet:

```js
let divElement=document.querySelection('div.someClass');
Array.from(divElement.querySelectionAll('img'))
.forEach(el=>{
    let div=document.createElement('div');
    divElement.insertBefore(div,el));
    div.appendChild(el);
});
```

For more information see [Element.insertBefore on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Comment: sorry I don't want to "append" the empty <div> tags before <img> tags. I want to wrap <img> tags inside the <div>

The output should be like this:

<div class="SomeClassName">
   <a href="https://abc.xyz">
      <span>
         <div>
            <img id="SomeImgID1" />
      </span>
      </div>
   </a>
   <a href="https://xyz.abc">
      <span>
         <div>
            <img id="SomeImgID2" />
         </div>
      </span>
   </a>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

iaMsUPerNOva finally i got you and i am here with solution .

```
<a class="image" href="https://abc.xyz"> <!--note this-->

$(function() {
        var node = $("a.image"); // This will copy your a tag so that img tag will also get copied.
    $(".SomeClassName").append('<div>hello</div>');//This will create a new div containing  hello text 
        $("a.image").remove(); // This will remove a tag which is already copied to node.
        $("SomeClassName").append(node); //Finally we are going to add newly created div to SomeClassName.  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what we want to do here involves two steps:

1. Find each `IMG` element inside your `DIV` with class `SomeClassName`.
2. For each of these `IMG` elements, create a new `DIV` and insert it before the element.

Here is how you do that.

```
/* document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList.
   The spread operator "..." converts it into an array,
   so that we can call the forEach method on it. */
[...document.querySelectorAll("div.SomeClassName img")].forEach(x => {
    // Here we create the new DIV
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    // Just some sample text to show
    div.textContent = "Hello!";
    // x.parentNode finds the parent of the IMG element.
    // The frst parameter of node.InsertBefore is the
    // element we want to insert as its child, and the
    // the second parameter is the reference element
    // before which this new element will be inserted
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(div, x);
});
```

Comment: Don't just answer with code, actually explain why it is helpful and how it works so that the asker can learn.

Comment: Thank you, Mr.X for your reply. I don't want to append a new <div> tag before <img>.
I want <img /> tag to be wrapped inside <div> instead of appending <div></div> before <img> so it looks like this

<div><img /></div>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for your responses. I forgot to mention before that I had another parent `<div>` and the final structure was like this.

```
<div class="ParentClassName">
   <div class="ChildClassName">Some Content</div>
   <div class="ChildClassName">Some Content2</div>
   <div class="ChildClassName">
      <a href="https://abc.xyz">
      <span>
      <img id="SomeImgID1" />
      </span>
      </a>
      <a href="https://xyz.abc">
      <span>
      <img id="SomeImgID2" />
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I could able to wrap all `<img>` tags inside `<div>` by doing the below step.
Note: If your classname is dynamic you can remove it from the query selectors and you can put only the selector element like `document.querySelector("div");`

```
 let divElement = document.querySelector("div.ParentClassName");
      Array.from(divElement.querySelectorAll("div.ChildClassName img")).forEach(
        (el) => {
          let div = document.createElement("div");
          el.parentElement.insertBefore(div, el);
          div.appendChild(el);
        }
      );
```

and my final output was

```
<div class="ParentClassName">
   <div class="ChildClassName">Some Content</div>
   <div class="ChildClassName">Some Content2</div>
   <div class="ChildClassName">
      <a href="https://abc.xyz">
         <span>
            <div>
               <img id="SomeImgID1" />
            </div>
         </span>
      </a>
      <a href="https://xyz.abc">
         <span>
            <div>
               <img id="SomeImgID2" />
            </div>
         </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```