# Replace an element with another element with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table element `<table id="my-table"></table>`. I want to replace the selected table with a `<div class="some-class></div>`. What is the fastest way to achieve this? I want to use pure JavaScript only.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not sure if the fastest but the most easy - document.querySelector('#my-table').outerHTML = document.querySelector('some-class');

Comment: @Daweed I cannot think of a safer way to replace the selected element itself. I've read it's not safe to replace the html directly

Comment: Duplicate: [How to replace DOM element in place using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript)

Comment: @ChrisG - I'm an idiot. Of **course** this is asked and answered.

Comment: *"I want to use pure JavaScript only."* JavaScript is a *language*, not an API (though like all languages it has a standard library -- which doesn't know anything about browsers). The native browser API you're looking for is the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: Got it, thanks all

Comment: @RifatBinReza - FWIW, I posted the answer I originally posted below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66470963/157247).