# How to insertBefore() element in body tag?

Tags: javascript, dom, insert, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to use insertBefore in js like this:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "test1";
document.body.insertBefore(p, null);

var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "test2";
document.body.insertBefore(p, null);
```

But that would add the last p element just before the close of the body tag, how could I use it so it will be added to the top when it opens? So the last element added will be the first element inside the body tag.

I tried:

```
document.body.insertBefore(p, document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```

But firebug shows:

**Node was not found" code: "8**

Comment: Try out document.body.prepend. Also, it is generally good practice to not set innerHTML. Use `oldNode.replaceWith(newNode)` or set `oldNode.innerText`

Comment: @Gibolt `textContent` should be preferred for setting text.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can get the first child of the `body` element with the `firstChild` property. Then use it as the reference.

```js
const p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = "test1";
document.body.insertBefore(p, document.body.firstChild);
```

I modernized your code for reasons :)

Comment: You should not push text to an element with `innerHTML`. Use `textContet` instead.

Comment: @Persijn It was for an example only, and back in 2011 you had to use `textContent` or `innerText` in IE, so this was more convenient.

Comment: agread, but i commented it since we no longer do this. Could you change/edit it?

Comment: @Persijn It's literally the code from the OP's question, but yes I can change it

Comment: Don't we answers question for the community? And not for a single user? We are not a helping service.

Answer (score 14):

### Modern Solution - `prepend`

```
document.body.prepend(p)
```

This is vanilla JS and is more readable than previous options. It is currently available in [all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dom-manip-convenience).

You can directly prepend strings, although they won't be 'p' tags

```
parent.prepend("This text!")
```

#### Related DOM methods

1. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656684/974045) - `parent.append`
2. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656649/974045) - `child.before` and `child.after`
3. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40444300/974045) - `child.replaceWith`

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert before something. `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` *is* the body element (the syntax is a bit of a trick to get the body element in all browsers)<sup>**<strike>1</strike>**</sup>. If you want to insert into the body, you want to insert before the first element of it. That could look like this:

```
var body   = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    newpar = document.createElement('p');
newpar.innerHTML = 'Man, someone just created me!';
body.insertBefore(newpar,body.childNodes[0]);
```

<sup>**1**</sup> <strike>in some browsers it's `document.body`, other `document.documentElement` etc., but in all browsers the tagname is `body`</strike>

Comment: Which browsers don't support `document.body`?

Comment: @alex you're right, every browser seems to support it. I think it's a trace in my memory from a long gone past.

Comment: @Kooilnc Thanks for getting back to me, I have a lot of `document.body` in the wild and was a little worried :P