# Prototype equivalent for jQuery before function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Is there any equivalent in Prototype for the jQuery [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method?

```
var new_id = new Date().getTime(); 
var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
$(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
```

The error occurs in the last row. I have replaced parent() method to up() ... but I dont know what I should use instead of `before()`

Comment: Does there have to be, why not just use plain JavaScript?

Comment: Have you searched an answer on Stack Overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618089/how-to-append-child-before-prototype

Comment: I believe it will be simpler using prototype. But if there is a simple solution using plain javascript it will be great as well.

Comment: var new_id = new Date().getTime();
var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
$(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id)); // here the error occurs. I have replaced parent() method to up() ... but i dont know what I should use instead of before()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Prototype, so my understanding of its API may be skewed by my familiarity with jQuery, but the `insert()` method seems to be what you're looking for:

```
$(link).up().insert({
    before : content.replace(regexp, new_id)
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6C7Ed/).

Assuming that the `content.replace()` produces a valid result of course. In plain JavaScript however this isn't that hard:

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; // any means to get a valid DOM node
link.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', content.replace(regexp, new_id));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6C7Ed/1/).

Or even:

```
var link = document.querySelector('a'),
    span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('First paragraph:'));

link.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(span, link.parentNode);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6C7Ed/2/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML).
  - [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/node.insertBefore).
- Prototype:

  - [`insert()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/insert/).